Nowhere analytic smooth solutions to analytic differential equations
There are several parts to this question. Clearly there exist "analytic" differential equations of a certain variety that have nowhere analytic solutions (e.g., $f'(x)=2f(2x)$ has the Fabius function as a solution and $f'$ is analytic in $f(2x)$). I want to know in more restricted cases whether differential equations that have convergent Taylor series expansions in their variables necessarily have analytic solutions.
Suppose $f(x_0,\dots,x_{n+2})$ is a real-valued analytic function. Let $g(x)=y$ be a solution to the differential equation $f(x,y,y',\dots,y^{(n)})=0$. Is $g$ necessarily analytic somewhere? What if $f(x,y,y',y'',\dots)=0$ with $f$ having infinitely many inputs?
I suspect the answer to the first question is yes but the second is no, however I am unsure how to prove it.
